# Merge multiple streams and write to sorted output stream

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

I recently stumbled upon this question in a couple of interviews. It goes as following:

You have a list of stream of numbers that you can read from asynchronously. Given a write stream for the consumer, how would you read the numbers from the streams, merge and sort them, and finally write to an output stream?

```
Input:

 1. stream 1: 1, 2, 3, 4...
 2. stream 2: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5...

Output: 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5....
```

We can assume the contract is as following:

```
final class Stream {
   public interface boolean isClosed();
   public interface int read();
}

// utility method to write numbers to consumer stream
public void write(Integer number);
```

My initial thoughts about this question was that its similar to [LRU cache buffer](https://www.interviewcake.com/concept/java/lru-cache). However, there are 2 problems with this:

- How do you merge and maintain the order and synchronization of read streams?
- How do you make sure the numbers are written without any delay? As once the write is performed, the write order can no longer be ensured for any further numbers in the stream?

I am sure there is a caveat here that I have misinterpreted or missed out completely. Any help on this would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Are the numbers in *a* stream strictly increasing?

Comment: According to the way you phrased the text of your question, you cannot assume that input streams are sorted, even if the example data happens to appear in ascending order, so you must read all data before you can write any of it. Since that seems unlikely, given the rest of the text, either you've misquoted the challenge, or it is expected of you to ask clarifying questions in the interview, showing you can correctly recognize and handle incomplete requirements (something that's way too common in real life).

Comment: Definitely will need more information, but my initial thoughts is that this problem has resemblance to [merge k sorted lists](https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-k-sorted-lists/)

Comment: @user7 for this case, yes the numbers are strictly increasing

Answer (score 1):

I shall assume that there are many streams, and each gives data in increasing order.

Now your stream interface has a small problem.  You can build on top of that a class that consists of pairs `(lastValue, stream)` which has methods `peek` (returns `lastValue`) and `readNext` (if `stream.isClosed()` returns `null`, else returns the pair `(stream.read(), stream)`.  And one more thing, we can add a `compareTo` method that first compares `lastValue` and then compares `stream.hashCode()`.

What these pairs buy us is that we can put them in a [PriorityQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html).  Which allows us to implement something like this logic:

```
construct initial pairs from streams
put them into a priority queue named pq
while 0 < pq.size()
    take the smallest pair p
    print p.peek()
    pNext = p.readNext()
    if pNext != null
        add pNext to pq
```

If `n` is the total amount of data between the streams, and `m` is the number of streams, this algorithm will take time `O(n log(m) + m)`.  The `+ m` bit only shows up if you started with a lot of streams that were closed.